# Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering - Sweet

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

I get the following error when rendering a SweetAlert.. not sure how to solve?

```
index.js:1451 Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.
    in n (at LoginOverlay/index.js:248)
    in div (at LoginOverlay/index.js:82)
    in Formik (at LoginOverlay/index.js:66)
    in LoginOverlay (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at Routes.js:270)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(MotionComponent))
    in ForwardRef(MotionComponent) (at Routes.js:263)
    in Switch (at Routes.js:262)
    in PresentationLayout (at Routes.js:261)
    in Route (at Routes.js:260)
    in Switch (at Routes.js:258)
    in Suspense (at Routes.js:257)
    in PresenceChild (created by AnimatePresence)
```

Code:

```
const LoginOverlay = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const { magic, login, clearError } = props;

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (magic.entity?.loggedIn && localStorage.getItem('did_token')) {
  //     //history.push('/business/home');
  //   }
  // }, [magic.loading, magic.showInfoDialog]);

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: ''
      }}
      validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
        email: yup
          .string()
          .email('Must be valid email address')
          .min(3)
          .required('Email is required')
      })}
      onSubmit={async (values, actions) => {
        console.log(values, props);
        props.login(values.email);
      }}>
      {(props) => (
        <div className="app-wrapper min-vh-100 bg-white">
          <div className="hero-wrapper w-100 bg-composed-wrapper bg-midnight-bloom min-vh-100">
            <div className="flex-grow-1 w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
              <div
                className="bg-composed-wrapper--image opacity-2"
                style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + hero6 + ')' }}
              />
              <div className="bg-composed-wrapper--bg bg-second opacity-7" />
              <div className="bg-composed-wrapper--content p-3 p-md-5">
                <Container>
                  <Card className="rounded-sm modal-content p-3 bg-white-10">
                    <Card className="rounded-sm overflow-hidden shadow-xxl font-size-sm p-3 p-sm-0">
                      <Row className="no-gutters">
                        <Col
                          lg="6"
                          className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column">
                          <Form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="divider-v divider-v-lg d-none d-lg-block" />
                            <div className="text-center mt-4">
                              <h1 className="font-size-xxl mb-1 font-weight-bold">
                                Login
                              </h1>
                              <br />
                              <p className="mb-0 text-black-50">
                                Enter you email below to sign up or sign in to
                                your account
                              </p>
                              <br />
                              <div className="mb-0 text-black-50">
                                <div className="form-group mb-6">
                                  <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    {...props.getFieldProps('email')}
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    invalid={
                                      props.errors.email && props.touched.email
                                    }
                                    valid={
                                      !props.errors.email && props.touched.email
                                    }
                                  />
                                  <FormFeedback>
                                    {props.errors.email}
                                  </FormFeedback>
                                </div>
                                <div className="text-center py-4">
                                  <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    disabled={
                                      magic.loading || props.isSubmitting
                                    }
                                    className="font-weight-bold w-50 my-2"
                                    color="second">
                                    Submit
                                  </Button>
                                  {/* <LaddaButton
                                    type="submit"
                                    className="m-2 btn btn-second"
                                    loading={(magic.loading || props.isSubmitting)}
                                    onClick={(e) => {
                                      e.preventDefault(); 
                                      props.submitForm();
                                    }}  
                                    data-style={EXPAND_LEFT}>
                                    Submit
                                  </LaddaButton> */}
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </Form>
                        </Col>
                        <Col
                          lg="6"
                          className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column bg-secondary">
                          <div className="p-3">
                            <div className="p-4">
                              <div className="d-block d-xl-flex">
                                <div className="mt-0 mt-xl-1 mb-md-2 mb-lg-0">
                                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                                    icon={['far', 'heart']}
                                    className="font-size-xl text-first"
                                  />
                                </div>
                                <div className="pl-0 pl-xl-3">
                                  <div className="text-black font-weight-bold font-size-lg mb-1">
                                    Have we anything for here?
                                  </div>
                                  <p className="mb-0 text-black-50">
                                    Have we anything for here?
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="p-4">
                              <div className="d-block d-xl-flex">
                                <div className="mt-0 mt-xl-1 mb-md-2 mb-lg-0">
                                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                                    icon={['far', 'lightbulb']}
                                    className="font-size-xl text-first"
                                  />
                                </div>
                                <div className="pl-0 pl-xl-3">
                                  <div className="text-black font-weight-bold font-size-lg mb-1">
                                    Have we anything for here?
                                  </div>
                                  <p className="mb-0 text-black-50">
                                    Have we anything for here?
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="p-4">
                              <div className="d-block d-xl-flex">
                                <div className="mt-0 mt-xl-1 mb-md-2 mb-lg-0">
                                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                                    icon={['far', 'user']}
                                    className="font-size-xl text-first"
                                  />
                                </div>
                                <div className="pl-0 pl-xl-3">
                                  <div className="text-black font-weight-bold font-size-lg mb-1">
                                    Have we anything for here?
                                  </div>
                                  <p className="mb-0 text-black-50">
                                    Have we anything for here?
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Card>
                  </Card>
                </Container>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="hero-footer w-100 pb-4">
              <Container>
                <div className="py-3 d-block d-lg-flex font-size-xs justify-content-between">
                  <div className="text-center d-block mb-3 mb-md-0 text-white">
                    XXXXX 2021
                  </div>
                  <Nav className="nav-transparent justify-content-center">
                    <NavItem>
                      <NavLinkStrap
                        className="text-white-50"
                        href="#/"
                        onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                        Privacy Policy
                      </NavLinkStrap>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem>
                      <NavLinkStrap
                        className="text-white-50"
                        href="#/"
                        onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                        Terms of Service
                      </NavLinkStrap>
                    </NavItem>
                  </Nav>
                </div>
              </Container>
            </div>
          </div>
          
            <SweetAlert
              title="Check your email"
              show={!magic.entity?.loggedIn && magic.showInfoDialog}
              html={`We emailed a magic link to ${props.values.email}</br>Click the link in your email and then return to this tab to log in or sign up.</br>`}
              type="info"
              showCancelButton={false}
              showConfirmButton={false}
            />
          
          
            <SweetAlert
              title="Error"
              show={!magic.entity?.loggedIn && magic.errorMessage}
              html={magic.errorMessage}
              type="error"
              showCancelButton={false}
              showConfirmButton={true}
              onConfirm={() => clearError()}
            />

            {
              (localStorage.getItem("did_token") || magic.entity?.loggedIn ) && <Redirect to="/business/home" />
            }                      
          

        </div>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check for any other alerts that is dependent. It happens when you are trying to access multiple alerts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).